# Reflections API not showing Interfaces having annotations

Tags: java, annotations, reflections

I am using the Reflections API to scan my java project and fetch all classes/interfaces having a particular annotation.
However it is just returning classes but not interfaces.

I am using the following:

```
Set<Class<?>> annotated = 
    reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Path.class);
```

Note : it is working for classes having Path annotation.

So is it that Reflections does not support scanning interfaces ? Or I have to code something else?

Comment: What is the type of reflections? From where does reflections scanning the classes and interfaces?

Comment: It is google reflections API. It is scanning classes from my class path. I am running this in eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections/blob/master/src/test/java/org/reflections/ReflectionsTest.java#L64)

Maybe you're not scanning all the relevant urls? In that case, try building the Reflections object properly (using ClasspathHelper.forClasspath() would scan everything, though it is too broad probably...)

Comment: The Interface was not in my classpath though i thought so. I just added the missing jar.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out:

```
@Documented
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Inherited
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MethodInfo{
    String author() default "Kuntal";
    String date();
    int revision() default 1;
    String comments();
}


public class AnnotationExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    @Override
    @MethodInfo(author = "Kuntal", comments = "Main method", date = "Nov 17 2012", revision = 1)
    public String toString() {
        return "Overriden toString method";
    }

    @Deprecated
    @MethodInfo(comments = "deprecated method", date = "Nov 17 2012")
    public static void oldMethod() {
        System.out.println("old method, don't use it.");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "deprecation" })
    @MethodInfo(author = "Kuntal", comments = "Main method", date = "Nov 17 2012", revision = 10)
    public static void genericsTest() throws FileNotFoundException {
        List l = new ArrayList();
        l.add("abc");
        oldMethod();
    }

}
```

Then you can use Reflection to parse java annotations from a class. Please note that Annotation Retention Policy should be RUNTIME otherwise it’s information will not be available at runtime and we wont be able to fetch any data from it.

```
public class AnnotationParsing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            for (Method method : AnnotationParsing.class
                    .getClassLoader()
                    .loadClass(("com.kuntal.annotations.AnnotationExample"))
                    .getMethods()) {
                // checks if MethodInfo annotation is present for the method
                if (method
                        .isAnnotationPresent(com.kuntal.annotations.MethodInfo.class)) {
                    try {
                        // iterates all the annotations available in the method
                        for (Annotation anno : method.getDeclaredAnnotations()) {
                            System.out.println("Annotation in Method '"
                                    + method + "' : " + anno);
                        }
                        MethodInfo methodAnno = method
                                .getAnnotation(MethodInfo.class);
                        if (methodAnno.revision() == 1) {
                            System.out.println("Method with revision no 1 = "
                                    + method);
                        }

                    } catch (Throwable ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SecurityException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks Kuntal, but my issue is that I am not able to scan interfaces having annotation using the reflection API. (Not annotation themselves being interfaces)
That means if I am searching for all classes and interfaces having 'Path' annotation, then the API should return me below interface cls as well.
`
@Path(value="xyz")
public interface cls{
}`